# How to compare each element of array to other elements?

Tags: arrays, swift

I need to find pairs in array, i wanted to do it with comparing arr[i] with others starting from arr[i+1] so i won't check for same value twice, but i can't get that going.
Here's what i've tried

```
func findPairs(_ ar: [Int]) -> Int {
    var pairs = 0
    for i in 0..<ar.count {
        var k = i + 1
        for k in 0..<ar.count {
            if ar[i] == ar[k] {
                pairs += 1
            }
        }
    }
    return pairs/2
}
```

Upd
to clarify, in the example i have, it was given as in array [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1] we have 3 pairs [1,1] [2,2] [3,3]

Comment: This question needs more clarification as to how pairs are defined and what the input array may look like (is it guaranteed to only contain singles or pairs or might it contain triplets or greater).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to use `i + 1` as the starting index in your inner loop, like that:

```
func findPairs(_ ar: [Int]) -> Int {
    var pairs = 0
    for i in 0..<ar.count {
        let m = i + 1
        for k in m..<ar.count {
            if ar[i] == ar[k] {
                pairs += 1
            }
        }
    }
    return pairs
}
```

Also, you can use another array to store the indexes of the pairs so that you do not use the same element for another pair:

```
func findPairs(_ ar: [Int]) -> Int {
    var pairs = 0
    var pairIndexes = [Int]()
    for i in 0..<ar.count where !pairIndexes.contains(i) {
        let m = i + 1
        for k in m..<ar.count where !pairIndexes.contains(k) {
            if ar[i] == ar[k] {
                pairs += 1
                pairIndexes.append(contentsOf: [i, k])
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return pairs
}
```

Comment: It kind of depends on the definition of a pair.  If I call your first function with `findPairs([4, 4, 4, 4, 4])`, I get the answer 10, which is correct for one definition.  Or maybe the answer should be 2.  Or 4 as you get with your 2nd function.

Comment: Exactly. The definition of pair is not so clear in the question. Also this `pairs/2` at the end is something I didn't understand.

Comment: @PhillipMills yeah, i agree, to clarify, in the example i have it was given as in array [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1] we have 3 pairs [1,1] [2,2] [3,3]

Comment: @Oleksii ok, so the second one is the correct for you.

Comment: @gcharita  Not quite.  The second one will find 4 pairs by matching [1, 1] twice.  I think the correct code will need to remove matching elements before looking for more.

Comment: @gcharita so even with input [4, 4, 4, 4, 4] it returns 4, that's what pairs/2 was about in my code example, it didn't work well anyway though...

Comment: @PhillipMills quite right, I forgot a `break` :) Answer updateded.

Comment: @gcharita could you please explain how break will work here? Will it just stop the "inner" for loop for going further?

Comment: @Oleksii of course. `break` in general will break (or stop) the loop that contains it. So, when the `if` check succeeds the inner loop will stop and the outer loop will continue through.

Comment: @Oleksii a more accurate explanation is here https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html

Answer (score 2):

The functional approach would be to get the total number of occurrences of the  elements and sum half of it:

```
func findPairs(_ ar: [Int]) -> Int {
    ar.reduce(into: [Int:Int]()) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 }.values.reduce(0) { $0 + $1/2 }
}
```

---

```
findPairs([1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1])  // 3
findPairs([4, 4, 4, 4, 4])      // 2
```

---

Or extending collection constraining the elements to hashable:

---

```
extension Collection where Element: Hashable {
    var numberOfPairs: Int {
        reduce(into: [Element:Int]()) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 }.values.reduce(0) { $0 + $1/2 }
    }
}
```

---

```
[1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1].numberOfPairs  // 3
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4].numberOfPairs      // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to find the number of pairs in the array.
So the following can work for you:

```
func findPairs(_ ar: [Int]) -> Int {
    var pairs = 0
    for i in 0..<ar.count {
        for k in (i+1)..<ar.count {
            if ar[i] == ar[k] {
                pairs += 1
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return pairs
}
```